# get the status of a toggle button in semantic UI

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I am trying to get the status of a toggle button in semantic UI but am having issues. The `state` and `isChecked` properties are coming back as undefined.

Here is my sandboxed example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>



<button class="ui toggle button" id="tgl">Select All</button>
 <script>
     $('#tgl').click(function(){      
          $(this).toggleClass('active');
          alert($(this).isChecked)
     });
</script>
```

As you can see, this comes back as undefined.

Comment: Try to use the hasClass method, in this way you can define active class when click on button

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_hasclass.asp

Comment: Ah yes, this orked `$(this).hasClass('active')` Thank you!